# When should the "Natural Language" PyPI classifier be used?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, pypi

There is a [list of classifiers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers) that we can define in `setup.py` to categorize our python package in [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org). Among those there are "`Natural Language`" classifiers for a few languages. When should those classifiers be included in a project's setup.py? Is it for packages related to Natural Language Processing or they should be used when the package's source code is written in a corresponding language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alefteris.

Although PyPI limits the use of classifiers for those in its list, there is no explanation on how to use each classifier on the list. [PyPA's sample project](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py) gives you a hint to some of them (lines 78 to 99), and also says using classifiers at all is optional!

The [concept behind classifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0301/#distutils-trove-classification) is better cataloguing the packages. This is also clear [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#classifiers). I quote and emphasize:

> Although the list of classifiers is often used to declare what Python versions a project supports, **this information is only used for searching & browsing projects on PyPI**, not for installing projects.

That is, it helps PyPI organize packages, so they can be found through search and browsing at PyPI's website.

If your package has anything to do with a natural language in the list, I strongly suggest you to include it as a classifier. It may help your package being found and better distributed.

By the way, classifiers [should not](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data) be used if your package is to be compatible with Python versions prior to 2.2.3 or 2.3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain what is a classifier and how they are used. I'm still not sure when it should be used though. For example, if there is a python package that does spell checking for Greek, is this an appropriate case to use the "Natural Language :: Greek" classifier?

Comment: Yes, for sure, if it helps identifying that package's functionalities. We can think the other way around: what are the inappropriate cases to use a certain classifier on a package? I think the package you described is still very appropriate for the Natural Language classifier.